# Do we have any chance of graduating any time soon?

Tags: discussion

This site has existed for over 5 years. Now that [Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) is implemented, we don't need to wait on a design to have a partial graduation. Our [Area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) are not perfect, but they're better in almost every category than what [Home Improvement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement), [Christianity](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity), [Role-playing Games](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games), and [Photography](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing) had when they graduated, even in our worst score. Can we expect to get at least partial graduation any time soon? If not, what do we still have to do to make that possible?

Comment: Do you have a source for "they're almost universally better than what Home Improvement, Christianity, Role-playing Games, and Photography had when they graduated, even in our worst score", or is that just from memory?

Comment: The source is the same as for our stats. So the Home Improvement stats are on [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement). Note that for any graduated site, Area51 reports the "At the end of beta" values for those statistics.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Now, according to the link you provided, Home Improvement launched (graduated) four years ago. I'm willing to bet that the bar for graduation has risen in the last four years. [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/254466) from last year seems to indicate that *something* changed, but I'm not really sure what exactly because I can't find any earlier standards.

Comment: I think the the general standards have been basically unchanged over time, and they were just always applied inconsistently. For example, two years ago we got [this answer](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1113/2537) indicating that our question rate at 3.8 questions per day was the primary concern. At around the same time (within a year), Christianity launched with 3.9 questions per day.

Comment: A big problem area for the site is self moderation where we seem to have items sit in the queue longer then any other site (last time I saw the stats) and if we move to a graduated status then we lose a lot of people who can help on the self moderation side of things.

Comment: That's surprising to me. Most of the time when I look at the review queue, it's empty or it has only a couple of items. And according to the Area51 stats, we currently have 56 users with at least 3k rep, out of a recommended 5. That should be more than enough to handle a few queue items a day.

Comment: I frequently see the indicator saying that there are multiple items that need to be reviewed even when it shows empty for me.

Comment: Indeed, you do have to look at the number in the top bar (which can be nonzero if there are things that you've reviewed but still need other reviews), but I haven't seen things staying here unusually long either.

Comment: I can't find the question on meta stack exchange where I saw the information so I have asked a new question asking about it.

Answer (score 5):

[As we announced last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/208518):

> **When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.**

As the numbers you point to show, you're still a bit off the mark there. We also don't see any compelling reason to consider Board & Card Games an exception to that.

I'd recommend you read through the post linked to above, since — as its title suggests — it provides "a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites" ;)

Comment: Is there any chance that we might be able to at least get the "Beta" label removed? That would be progress if nothing else.

Comment: So to clarify, the point here is that in some cases sites *previously* launched with <10 questions/day, but it's no longer going to happen - i.e. it's in some cases *harder* to graduate now?

Comment: Or is the idea that you might sometimes make exceptions to the 10/day rule, and you did that in the past as well, for these sites? (It does look like it was generally justified: Home Improvement, Photography, and RPG are all above 10/day now.)

Comment: I'm surprised that questions per day is so important to graduating this site. The majority of questions we see here are rules questions, and there are a finite number of these questions per game. 4.8 questions about the rules across popular board games doesn't seem that low. And the fact that we're under 2.5 answers per questions fits this, too; if there is a rules clarification, we don't need 2.5 responses to answer it. But we clearly have an active community, given how many high rep users we have. It seems like not all stats should be treated equally for all sites.

Comment: I understand where this answer is coming from. I tried to go for the Fanatic badge last year, and found the amount of new content I got each day to be a bit disappointing. I think it would be worthwhile to investigate a way to broaden our scope a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a [query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275921/review-queue-statistics) to show the stats of the review queue from meta stack exchange. From what it looks like it seems that some of the review queues can take a day or more to be dealt with and that will only get slower if the privileges to deal with them increase.

```
select rtt.name
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 1 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Active]
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 2 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Completed]
     , sum( case 
            when rt.reviewtaskstateid = 3 then 1
            else 0
            end ) as [Invalidated]
     , min(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Minhours]
     , Max(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Maxhours]
     , avg(datediff(hh, creationdate, deletiondate)) as [Avghours]
from reviewtasks rt
inner join reviewtasktypes rtt on rtt.id = rt.reviewtasktypeid
group by rtt.name
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you realize that every site potentially faces this issue when looking to graduate, and that we have an *order of magnitude* more users with the right privileges than recommended.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I understand that but my point was that clearing items from the review queue is already slow on this site compared to other sites and reducing the number of people who can do it will only slow it down further.

Comment: And my point is that the queue never has more than a few items anyway. Reducing the number of eligible reviewers to **fifty-six** is unlikely to have a significant effect on our ability to process six items in a timely manner.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Maybe, Maybe not, but that information is something that needs to be considered in the graduation process since it will have an impact on quality of the site.

Comment: We have no idea how graduation will affect the review queues. Maybe reducing the reviewer pool to only ten times the average number of queue items will increase the time it takes for queue items to resolve. Maybe having more active mods will reduce the time. And this probably should have been mentioned earlier, but if you read the post I linked to in the question, you'll see that the first phase of graduation actually doesn't involve increasing privilege requirements, so this entire discussion is actually irrelevant to the question I was asking.

Comment: @murgatroid99 We still need to think about what changes will happen so that when the requirements are raised there are still enough users able to keep the site properly moderated. One key fact we don't know currently is how active the 56 users you mention are currently in the review queues and how active they will be after graduation. I am not saying we shouldn't graduate because of the review queue numbers but we should take them into account.

Comment: It's likely that the 56 users with at least 3000 rep are among the most active out of all the users with at least 350 rep, because they've been on the site, earning rep.

Comment: I am slow to review items because [the little number that shows how many items need review lies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238472/254466). I've developed a tolerance for that indicator.