# Can we get an exception to the graduation requirements on account of our age and other good stats?

Tags: discussion

In 2016 we were [told](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1422/2537) that the following hard graduation requirement had been instated, preventing this site from graduating:

> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.

In the four years since [that rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) was established, the following sites have graduated with fewer than 9 questions per day on average:

- [Quantitative Finance](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance)
- [Philosophy](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2578/philosophy)
- [Aviation](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation)
- [Japanese Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language)
- [Musical Practice and Performance](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance)
- [Anime & Manga](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538/anime-manga)

Given that these sites did not meet the stated requirements, I can only assume that they met some alternative requirements or otherwise got an exception to the requirements. This site has been in beta for 8 years and most of our other stats are very strong. Does this qualify us for these alternative requirements?

Comment: Writing (another very old site) has been asking to graduate for about a year and a half.  So far we have been rebuffed because of the 10 QPD rule, much to our frustration.  We usually average around 5-6; we had a question drive and topped 10 QPD for a few weeks, but they want to see a sustained level.  We'd be happy if they would just drop the "beta"; our site, like this one, isn't *provisional* or *in flux*, which is what "beta" usually conveys.

Comment: So the question becomes basically how to get above 10 questions a day? Is crowdfunding some BGG advertising out of the question? One of the problems I see for this stack is the overlap in BGG's function and ours. But BGG very much is a discussion site, so perhaps trying to pull some of its question and answer traffic across could work?

Comment: [I have written about this before](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/graduating-from-beta-generating-more-questions-per-day/1679#1679); essentially it is my belief that this site does not have the **potential** to sustain 10 questions per day. I strongly suspect that if you added in every on-topic question from every competing site, and filtered out duplicates, you still wouldn't consistently reach 10 questions per day.

Answer (score 1):

More of an observation than an answer.

Our average questions / day is 3.3.  Well below all the other sites you mentioned.  The lowest of which was 5.7, most above 7.0.  Most well above twice what we generate per day.  The stated requirement is 10/day.

All our other Site51 statistics are excellent, especially as compared to the sites you mentioned.

So, your question comes down to, is it okay to graduate, if we have a very low number of questions / day?

Comment: That's basically accurate. The goal of the question was in some sense to say "Other sites graduated without meeting the requirements we were given. Did they meet some different set of requirements, and if so are we also meeting those?"